# Storing 2D array points in to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

sorry if the title is miss leading or not informative. I could not state it how I want it to look like.

I have a 2D array in java

```
        private JButton[] [] JbGrid = new JButton[30] [21];
```

And what I want to do is grab the 10 value in the first array and the 11th value in the second array and them story them in a single variables .

If this is not possible, two variables should work.

For example, you can see that I have stored the numbers from the array in to the MOUSE_X and MOUSE_Y, but this was easy because it would update the value on click.

```
    for(int i = 0; i<30; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j<21; j++)
            {
                if(e.getSource()==JbGrid[i][j])
                {
                   MOUSE_X = j;
                   MOUSE_Y = i;


                  // jPpanelMain.revalidate();
                  // jPpanelMain.repaint();
                   runTimer();
                   reColour();
                   System.out.println("Mouse X: "+MOUSE_X+" Mouse Y: "+MOUSE_Y);
                }
            }
    }
```

How will I be able to store values in to an variable(s) from the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking for a class that will store the x and y values you could use `Point`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: I've use points in action script 3, but I'm not sure how you will place co ordinates from an array in to a point.

Comment: @Moynul I'm not sure I understand your question. I was suggesting storing the values in a point like this `Point p = new Point(j, i)` or alternatively `Point p = new Point(MOUSE_X, MOUSE_Y)`.